# Changing ASP.NET MVC default folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to change around the folder organization to the following and still have MVC work.

P1

- Controllers
- Models
- Views

P2

- Controllers
- Models
- Views

etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks a lot like the new feature area's which is available in [MVC 2](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx) though it is currently in preview and will be release with VS 2010.

If you want to do it yourself without using areas then check out [this article on view engines](http://www.coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/)

Answer (score 1):

as said before, the Areas feature is what you are looking for. 
If you are using vs2010, then although you have MVC2, you don't have the tools for creating the areas - these are only available on vs 2008, when you install the MVC2 rc

to make it happen follow the instructions at the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28VS.100%29.aspx
as you can see the menu options are missing so:

1. download the example project from there.
2. build the directory structure at your solution according to the example
3. change the AreaRegistration.cs to match your area name
4. add AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); at the RegisterRoutes function at the global.asax, right after the IgnoreRoute

NOTE: the namespaces shuold contain .Areas.
for More explanations search at stackoverflow for asp-net-mvc-2-beta-single-project-area-registration-getting-http-404 (since this is the first time i post an answer - SO doesn't let me append more then 1 link, go fugure..)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable, I think the default folder structure is just a suggestion.  I've seen before in some documentation that larger projects would likely be split up differently, possibly even among multiple assemblies.

The only thing I would think would cause some trouble would be the views.  Since controller actions are mapped to them only by file name.  I know there's some way to change them, but I have not had to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own viewengine to solve the paths. That sounds like a very strange idea, but the ViewEngine class is actually responsible for 2 things: locating a view and rendering a view to the httpresponse. The thing you have to change is the locating part, you can just inherit the default aspxviewengine and change the view locating part.